# Sorting array of structs in C using qsort

Tags: c, sorting, struct

Let's define a struct named "Edge".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Edge{
    int first;
    int second;
    float score;
};

struct Edge* newEdge(int first, int second, float score){
    struct Edge* edge = (struct Edge*)malloc(sizeof(struct Edge*));
    edge->first = first;
    edge->second = second;
    edge->score = score;
    return edge;
}
```

Given an array of edges, each of which consists of two vertices and a score, I have to sort the edges in descending/ascending order of their scores. I've written a comparator function. The following is what I've tried. However, it doesn't produce the correct output.

```
int comparator_function(const void *v1, const void *v2){
    struct Edge* e1 = (struct Edge*) v1;
    struct Edge* e2 = (struct Edge*) v2;
    if(e1->score < e2->score){
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(){
    struct Edge* edges[5];
    edges[0] = newEdge(1, 2, 1.23);
    edges[1] = newEdge(4, 3, 3.222);
    edges[2] = newEdge(2, 2, 5.222);
    edges[3] = newEdge(5, 1, 4.222);
    edges[4] = newEdge(3, 4, 2.4);
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        printf("%d, %d, %f\n", edges[i]->first, edges[i]->second, edges[i]->score);
    }
    printf("\n\n");

    qsort(edges, 5, sizeof(struct Edge*), comparator_function);

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        printf("%d, %d, %f\n", edges[i]->first, edges[i]->second, edges[i]->score);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the quicksort I'm getting is -

```
4, 3, 3.222000
5, 1, 4.222000
2, 2, 5.222000
1, 2, 1.230000
3, 4, 2.400000
```

I'm not sure if my compare function is right or not. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, the allocation

```
    struct Edge* edge = (struct Edge*)malloc(sizeof(struct Edge*));
```

is wrong. You have to allocate for the structure, not the pointer.

It should be

```
    struct Edge* edge = malloc(sizeof(*edge));
```

or

```
    struct Edge* edge = malloc(sizeof(struct Edge));
```

(Also note that casting results of `malloc()` is [considered as a bad practice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc))

Then, the comparision function is wrong.

- You have to return `-1` when the first element is "smaller" than the second element.
- The arguments are pointers to the elements (`struct Edge*` in this case).

It should be like this:

```
int comparator_function(const void *v1, const void *v2){
    /* correct casting type and add dereferencing */
    struct Edge* e1 = *(struct Edge**) v1;
    struct Edge* e2 = *(struct Edge**) v2;
    if(e1->score < e2->score){
        return 1;
    }
    /* add this */
    if(e1->score > e2->score){
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. The qsort function is now working properly. However, if I don't cast `struct Edge*` before malloc, it's showing the error that "invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'Edge*''. Is there a way to allocate memory without casting?

Comment: It looks like you are compiling your code as C++. Use C compiler to compile C code. The extension of C source file should be `.c`.

Answer (score 1):

The comparison function passed to `qsort` is supposed to return:

- less than 0, if the value on the left is smaller
- 0, if the values are equal
- greater than 0, if the value on the left is larger

Your comparison function only returns the values 0 and 1, so there's no way for the left argument to be larger.  You need to add an extra case to account for that.

The other problem is that since your array element types are `struct Edge *`, the pointers passed to the comparison function will be of type `struct Edge **` so you need to make a change related to that.

```
int comparator_function(const void *v1, const void *v2){
    struct Edge * const *e1 = v1;
    struct Edge * const *e2 = v2;
    if((*e1)->score < (*e2)->score){
        return 1;
    } else if((*e1)->score > (*e2)->score){
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Also, you're not allocating the proper amount of memory:

```
struct Edge* edge = (struct Edge*)malloc(sizeof(struct Edge*));
```

This only allocates space for a pointer, not the entire struct.  You want:

```
struct Edge* edge = malloc(sizeof(struct Edge));
```

Comment: The array is `struct Edge* edges[5];`, so the 3rd argument of `qsort()` should be `sizeof(struct Edge*)` or `sizeof(*edges)`, not `sizeof(struct Edge)`.

Comment: @MikeCAT Fixed, and found some other issues.

Comment: @dbush, Thank you for the quick response. The qsort function is now working properly. However, if I don't cast `struct Edge*` before malloc, it's showing the error that "invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'Edge*''. Is there a way to allocate memory without casting?

Comment: @SaankhyaMondal C allows casting to/from a `void *` without a cast.  If you're getting that error that means you're compiling with a C++ compiler.  Use a C compiler instead.